# React App with css module multiple classes

Tags: css, reactjs, module

i created a basic react app like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import style from './Button.module.scss';


export default class Button extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <button className={[style.class, 'awesome', 'great'].join(' ')}>
                hello world
            </button>
        );
    }
}
```

the css/scss:

```
.class {
    background: pink;
    color: red;


    /* not working */
    &:is(.awesome) {
        border-width: 2px;
    }

    /* not working either */
    &.awesome {
        border-width: 2px;
    }

    /* works */
    &:not(.great) {
        border-style: dotted;
    }
}
```

the problem:
the sublass `.awesome` is not working, whereas `.great` works fine.
Can you fix the code so the `.awesome` will work.
I need some subclass of the .button, so i can toggle them at runtime.

this is the generated css on the browser,
the `.awesome` is not generated but `.great` generated.

```
.Button_class__1tDJY:not(.Button_great__3yeAv) {
    border-style: dotted;
}
.Button_class__1tDJY {
    background: pink;
    color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you should pass the classes declared at your css modules through your `styles` object, instead of passing a string:

```
      <button className={[styles.class, styles.awesome, styles.great].join(' ')}>
          hello world
      </button>
```

Comment: you are welcome :) if you feel that answer your question you could consider to check as the accepted answer, cheers